# Push in typescript is appending the last modified object in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript

I am trying to create an array out of a modified object but the `Array<any>.push()` method always appends the object that gets modified at the end of the loop. Here is sample code that I am trying to work with:

```
let data: any = JSON.parse('{"messages":[{"id":"1234"},{"id":"2345"},{"id":"3456"}]}');
let myObject:any;
let idMapping: any[] = [];
for(let index = 0; index < 1; index++) {
    myObject = {DocID: "", index: index};
    for (let val of data.messages) {
        myObject.DocID = val.id;
        // console.log("After update: ", myObject); // this gives me the correct object
        idMapping.push(myObject);
    }
}
console.log(idMapping) // array with same identical values, infact the last modified value in for loop
```

This is giving me a list of same objects against what I expected it to be a list of objects having different `DocID`.

I am new to typescript and Nodejs, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modify and add the *same* object to the array over and over again!

Instead you should create a new object every iteration:

```
let data: any = JSON.parse('{"messages":[{"id":"1234"},{"id":"2345"},{"id":"3456"}]}');
let idMapping: any[] = [];
for(let index = 0; index < 1; index++) {
   
    for (let val of data.messages) {
       let myObject = {DocID: "", index: index};
        myObject.DocID = val.id;
        // console.log("After update: ", myObject); // this gives me the correct object
        idMapping.push(myObject);
    }
}
console.log(idMapping)
```

Comment: but the object has a different value for each iteration, does push() only pushes the reference to the object or a copy of the object?

Comment: @adtyson JavaScript never copies an object unless you explicitly tell it do so, so no. You only add a reference.